# How to properly display <img> tags found in returned json object

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am fetching json from the web using volley. One of the json objects ("content"), has <img> tags embedded in the string returned.

With the code below, I have successfully parsed and displayed the objects but the images in "content" are not displaying.
So I wanted the images to display in the positions that they are found in the "content" object.

**FruitDetails**

```
public class FruitDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "FruitDetails";


    TextView fruitTitle, fruitContent;
    NetworkImageView authorImg;
    ImageLoader AuthImgLoader;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit_details);

        fruitTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dfruit_title);
        fruitContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dfruit_content);
        authorImg = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.author_img);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            fruitTitle.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fruitTitle"));
            fruitContent.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fruitContent"));
        } else {

                loadFruit();

        }
    }

    private void loadFruit() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadFruit called");

        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        int news_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("FruitId", -1);
        Log.d(TAG, "You clicked fruit id " + news_id);

        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest( DetailConfig.GET_DURL + news_id, null,


                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("Debug", response.toString());

                        //Dismissing progressbar;
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        //Calling method to parse json array
                        parseFruit(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }

    //This method will parse json data of fruit
    private void parseFruit(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing fruit array");


            try {
                String title = jsonObject.getString(DetailConfig.TAG_DFRUIT_TITLE);
                fruitTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));

                JSONObject pAuthor = jsonObject.getJSONObject("author");
                String authorimg = pAuthor.getString("avatar");

                AuthImgLoader = VolleyRequest.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
                AuthImgLoader.get(authorimg, ImageLoader.getImageListener(authorImg, R.drawable.ic_author, R.drawable.ic_author));
                authorImg.setImageUrl(authorimg, AuthImgLoader);


                String content = jsonObject.getString(DetailConfig.TAG_DFRUIT_CONTENT);
                fruitContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("fruitTitle", fruitTitle.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("fruitContent", fruitContent.getText().toString());

    }

}
```

I have seen [the accepted  answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521900/6181476) but I am having problems trying to implement it it keeps telling me "cannot resolve symbol `urlDrawable`.

**UILImageGetter**

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;



public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter{
    Context c;
    TextView conatiner;
    UrlImageDownloader urlDrawable;

    public UILImageGetter(View textView, Context context) {
        this.c = context;
        this.conatiner = (TextView) textView;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        urlDrawable = new UrlImageDownloader(c.getResources(), source);
        urlDrawable.mDrawable = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_thumb);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(source, new SimpleListener(urlDrawable));
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    private class SimpleListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {
        UrlImageDownloader mUrlImageDownloader;

        public SimpleListener(UrlImageDownloader downloader) {
            super();
            mUrlImageDownloader= downloader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
            int height = loadedImage.getHeight();

            int newWidth = width;
            int newHeight = height;

            if (width > conatiner.getWidth()) {
                newWidth = conatiner.getWidth();
                newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
            }

            if (view != null) {
                view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
                view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            }

            Drawable result = new BitmapDrawable(c.getResources(), loadedImage);
            result.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            mUrlImageDownloader.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            mUrlImageDownloader.mDrawable = result;

            conatiner.setHeight((conatiner.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
            conatiner.invalidate();
        }

    }

    private class UrlImageDownloader extends BitmapDrawable {
        public  Drawable mDrawable;

        public UrlImageDownloader(Resources resources, String filepath) {
            super(resources, filepath);
            mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, filepath);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mDrawable != null) {
                mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the true answer here is that you'll need a proper HTML parser.

Comment: `has <img> tags embedded in the string returned`...So, can you post the content of that string?

Comment: @BNK I have added the sample to my question. I was thinking `Html.ImageGetter`, could it do it?

Comment: IMO, you can use some `String` methods such as indexOf, substr... to get all the actual Urls of the images (`"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Inline_Links.gif"` for example), then use `NetworkImageView` of Volley or use Picasso to load

Comment: @BNK how can I do that please?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998163/android-java-get-html-image-tag-from-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079423/regular-expression-to-get-an-attribute-from-html-tag?lq=1. About Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/. About NetworkImageView http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image

Comment: The only real image in that content you added is this link. Maybe you should just give the URL itself instead of some sample JSON. https://s.w.org/images/core/4.5/preview-icons-560.png

Comment: @cricket_007 I have done as you requested, the question have been updated.

Comment: Okay, so you definitely need an HTML parser. That JSON returns the whole WordPress page. Maybe an alternative would be use a different API address to get just the media on the page, but I don't know WordPress too well

Comment: But the result is in json, can jsoup do it? Can jsoup fetch the title, format the content and display the images where they are supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used **UILImageGetter** above, then came to **FruitDetails** and wrote

`protected com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader mImageLoader;`

before **onCreate**.

In onCreate, I wrote

`mImageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));`.

Then I also changed

`fruitContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));`

in **FruitDetails** to

`Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(content, new UILImageGetter(fruitContent, this), null);
                fruitContent.setText(spanned);`

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one is if the Json object is just a string with the following syntax (without the spaces in the img tags):

```
<img src= "https://www.myWebstie/images/myimgx92dp.png" />
```

and!!! you know it won't change then you can just substring it:

```
String response = "this is your image link";
int x = response.length();
x -= 3;
String subString = new String(response.substring(10, x));
```

so for example 10 for img tag + the src= at the beggining of the string and 3 for the closing tag at the end of the string.

As for your example you should notice that sometimes there is additional info in the img tag like width and height so make sure you substring the link without it and also learn from it how big the picture should be in your app (dont forget that there's px vs dp difference).

---

I checked the content you posted here.

If this is realy the website you are trying to parse I would suggest to find a 3rd party library to parse html objects.

Seems like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) might do the trick but I have never used it or Html.ImageGetter before although jsoup might seem as the better option for the content you added.

you will just need to try both and check what's the better solution for you.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051009/android-replace-img-tag-with-imageviews) as well.

Please be aware that if you are going to download and show multiple images and maybe even videos you should use volley  for the download as well (after you retrieved all the images links).

If it's just one picture as mentioned before and that content was just for example I would still recommend to just substring it.

Comment: There is a `src` attribute in an img tag. The URL isn't inside the tags

Comment: I'm not the OP, so nope, but if the response is HTML, then that's not how img tags work

Comment: if it isn't a link i have no idea what else could it be, maybe an image decoded to string? which then you will need to sunstring as well to get rid of the tags and afterward you would still need to decode the string to an image.

Comment: I'm replying to you @cricket_007 , yes its an additional library but you should check what you are compiling - "compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0", as you can see its com.android.volley, as far as i heared a chinese guy I think started it and google probably bought it and changed it a bit, they also implemented/embeded (not sure if what's the right word) it even on Android Developer website.

Comment: And it was also presented at google I/O 2013 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo

Comment: What about `Html.ImageGetter`?

Comment: @roee, @cricket_007, can I do it with `Html.ImageGetter`?

Comment: Just did, I updated my answer including the first part as cricket_007 suggested. let me know how it went, I'm curious =D

Comment: While it contains multiple images, the images are in varying positions. Can jsoup parse json? I thought it's only for html?  I have decided to adopt the answer I rejected but it's still giving me problems. I have updated the question with the **UILImageGetter** class

Comment: @Roee please can you take a look at it?

Comment: To get the content you need need to parse json, but the content itself is in html which as far as I could see jsoup is able to do, check their examples under the "cockbook" tab it.

Comment: about the ImageGetter as said I never used it before so you would just need to add breakpoint and debug, I think the content you pass to it should be only a singe img tag with the closure (so only 1 picture at a time), you cant pass all the content you added to your question, that's why I said jsoup seems better since it have the ability to parse the whole content at once.

Comment: I'll check it now but I just wanted to let you know that after the parsing, the text is formatted and can be read, the only problem is that there are blue small rectangles where the images are supposed to be.