# Why am I getting "cannot resolve symbol urlDrawable" in this class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, android-json

I'm trying to display <img> tags in json string and I using the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521900/6181476) but Android Studio is complaining  "cannot resolve symbol `urlDrawable`

Please can anybody tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

**UILImageGetter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;


public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter{
    Context c;
    TextView conatiner;
    urlDrawable;

    public UILImageGetter(View textView, Context context) {
        this.c = context;
        this.conatiner = (TextView) textView;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        urlDrawable = new UrlImageDownloader(c.getResources(), source);
        urlDrawable.drawable = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_thumb);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(source, new SimpleListener(urlDrawable));
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    private class SimpleListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {
        UrlImageDownloader mUrlImageDownloader;

        public SimpleListener(UrlImageDownloader downloader) {
            super();
            mUrlImageDownloader= downloader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
            int height = loadedImage.getHeight();

            int newWidth = width;
            int newHeight = height;

            if (width > conatiner.getWidth()) {
                newWidth = conatiner.getWidth();
                newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
            }

            if (view != null) {
                view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
                view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            }

            Drawable result = new BitmapDrawable(c.getResources(), loadedImage);
            result.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            mUrlImageDownloader.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            mUrlImageDownloader.mDrawable = result;

            conatiner.setHeight((conatiner.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
            conatiner.invalidate();
        }

    }

    private class UrlImageDownloader extends BitmapDrawable {
        public  Drawable mDrawable;

        public UrlImageDownloader(Resources resources, String filepath) {
            super(resources, filepath);
            mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, filepath);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mDrawable != null) {
                mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned a type to urlDrawable; 
This portion of code contains the error:

```
public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter{
    Context c;
    TextView conatiner;
    urlDrawable;
```

Try this:

```
public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter{
    Context c;
    TextView conatiner;
    UrlImageDownloader urlDrawable;
```

Comment: In which method should I do that?

Comment: right above this line: `public UILImageGetter(View textView, Context context) {`

Comment: At the top of your class after 'public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter{' you have three variables. The bottom one.

Comment: Updated my answer to show the code that contains the error and the code you should use

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a [strongly typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), which means that all variables must be declared as being of some type.

Since you don't specify a type for `urlDrawable`, the compiler doesn't understand that you're declaring a variable.

Simply replace

```
urlDrawable;
```

with

```
UrlImageDownloader urlDrawable;
```

Comment: Should I do that for all instances of `urlDrawable` or just the first one?

Comment: You need to do it for every variable of type `URLImageDownloader` that you declare. I see that you're already doing it for `UrlImageDownloader mUrlImageDownloader;` for example. Of course you only have to do this when you [declare a variable](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/declaringvars.htm), not when you use it!